# API wrong level shown on Android Studio

Tags: development-environment

I develop Android apps in Android Studio. I had on my GT- S 6201 the Gingerbread version,API 10 if I am not wrong,I have updated to 4.4.2,that means API which is API 19 I think,and my problem is that on my Android Studio is shows at my device 4.4.2, but API 10,and I just don't know why, and of course because of that I can run apps on my device with API bigger than 10,but I have API 19.